# Recognizing domain redirection

Tags: php, http

I have two domain for my site. The main site is *example.net*, and I have *example.com*.

If someone type *example.com* (or *www.example.com*, *http://example.com* or whatever) then I redirect them to *example.net* (my provider set domain redirecting).

So, is it possible, to take into a php variable if someone come from *.com* or directly type *.net*?

Thank you

Comment: Can you clarify the question? What information will be in the php variable? Is it that you want to have a php variable like $from_com=true; or $from_com=false; ? You should be able to use the variable $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; to see where they have come from. Note that referer is misspelled on purpose.

Comment: Yes something like you wrote. ($from=false; true). But im not sure if i can use HTTP_Referrer in this case. See Answer 2 - comment 2.

Comment: If you can give us the real address, we can see how the redirect is working and give you better advice. If the provider is doing the redirect correctly, it should be a 302, changed status. Can you do a var_dump of the $_SERVER variable and see what information is actually in it? Do you have access to this site right now?

Answer (score 2):

If the host is doing the redirecting and you don't have control over it, then it might be worth looking at `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` depending on how they are doing the redirect. Note that this is header not guaranteed to be there and can be spoofed by the client.

Comment: certainly don't follow the answer below, it would just create further issues with proper indexing and possibly duplicates.

Comment: If someone type MYSITE.COM (wich is auto-redirect to .UK), then HTTP_REFERER will be MYSITE.COM? 
I know if i use header (location...) in php, then http_referer will be the source url. But if the service provider do the redirecting HTTP_Referrer do the same? So will be the source URL?

Answer (score -1):

why don't use just redirect them to `.net?from=com` ?

Comment: I've edited your answer so it makes sense with Gumbo's edits.

Comment: If i use this simple redirect, then my site seems duplicated for robots.

Comment: And why should'nt it do if it IS a duplicate?